# Do Executors use the thread that they were created from?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am using 2 thread pools, each for a difference purpose (their purposes being irrelevant for this question). The pools are all created from the same initial thread as follows:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService pool1
    = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ManagerFactory(group, "Cached"));
private ExecutorService pool2
    = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3, new ManagerFactory(group, "Scheduled"));
```

The `ManagerFactory` class:

```
private class ManagerFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    private final ThreadGroup group;
    private final String name;

    private ManagerFactory(ThreadGroup group, String name) {
        this.group = group;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        final Thread t = new Thread(group, r);
        t.setName(name + " Manager Thread");
        return t;
    }
}
```

1. **When these thread pools are created, will they ever use the thread they were created on to execute a submitted task?**
2. **If the answer to the above is no, is there ever a delay when submitting a new task to be executed?**

   By this I am not referring to a delay before the task is executed, as I am aware schedulers cannot guarantee when a task will be executed. To better clarify, refer to the following example: 
   I submit a task on the EDT. Will the EDT hang at all while the task is being submitted?
3. **How can you tell which `ExecutorServices` will use the calling thread and which will not?**

Comment: simple questions: 1. no 2. yes

Comment: 1 is actually *maybe*, but only if you're using an Executor with a `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`.

Comment: EDT, in a loop, takes tasks from its queue, and then executes them. The access to the queue is synchronized. If EDT takes the task exactly when another task is being submitted by another thread, then EDT (or that thread) waits for negligible period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is indeed: no*. The thread that the executor is created from is not under the control of the executor, so it cannot use this thread to run tasks on.

When exactly tasks are executed is subject to the thread scheduler, and there are no guarantees about when exactly newly submitted tasks will be executed. You can't make any assumptions about the order or the exact timing of when threads are scheduled.

*) Actually, it depends on the implementation of the `ExecutorService` you are using. But most implementations, such as the ones returned by `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` and `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` create their own thread pools to run tasks.

To answer your third question: look in the API documentation of the specific `ExecutorService` implementation that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I suppose I should have been more clear on the second question: I am not asking if there is a delay before the task is executed, I know there is. I am asking if there is a delay when the task is added.

So for example, if I add a task from the EDT, would the EDT hang at all?

Comment: Actually, that's not true. The thread used by the executor is up to the executor, and may be the main thread. There is nothing in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) (ie contract) that says it must use a different thread.

Comment: That depends on the exact implementation of the `ExecutorService`, but probably what it does is just add the task to a queue, which is not an operation that takes a lot of time, so it's not expected that the EDT would hang on that.

Comment: @Bohemian Maybe not in general, but when you create an `ExecutorService` with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` or `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` then those executors will not use the thread you created them from.

Comment: I suppose so - as coded it won't, but your answer seemed to be a blanket one. Edit your answer (any change will do) so I can un-downvote

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Executors can use the main thread, but your code won't.

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), the contract of an Executor is to run a Runnable. How it does that is up to the Executor.

In reality, implementations of Executor - including the ones you've coded to use - do use other threads, but it is conceivable that when submitted, an executor simply runs the code immediately - in the callers thread.

Comment: True, but possibly misleading.  @user3144349 asked, will the ExeuctorService use the thread that _created_ it.  An Executor may use the thread that _submits_ a job, but it will never use the thread that created the service unless that happens to be the same thread that submits a job.